# Warnings during compilation, but programme works; what is to do?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, g++, osx-lion

I compile the following programme from source (code is written in C++): http://www.stanford.edu/group/hadlylab/ssc/index.html

The author recommends to use the g++ compiler with `g++ *.cpp -fpermissive`.
As this is recommend for Linux machines, while I am working on a Mac (OS X 10.7), I cannot say if this works as intended on my machine.
I get a lot of warnings, but the code compiles and eventuelly runs without any further error messages.

However, I am still worried that the script could be faulty, because of the compilation errors/warnings, and because of following the compile description for Linux, while compiling it under OS X 10.7.

Hence my question:

Should I (a) be worried that the programme could produce faulty results,
or (b) ignore the warnings during compilation because it compiles and is executable,
or (c) should I try another compiler, and if so, which one could do the job?

Comment: C++ script? There must be a misunderstanding

Comment: BTW, Stingery, you have a real problem with terminology here. One does not general refer to a c or c++ source package as a *"script"* but as *"the code"*. One then *"builds"* (or sometimes *"makes"*) the code to produce an executable. You'll get better help if you use the right nomenclature.

Comment: I apologise for using wrong terminology. I hope my corrections make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your difficulties related to changes in the version of

- the build tools (make, automake, etc)
- the compiler and related tools (g++, ld, ldd, libtool, etc)
- the libraries on the system

between the earlier versions of Mac OS and the current one.

Your first step is going to be finding out what *changed* between 10.6 and 10.7. 
Then go through the build mechanism (is there a `configure` script or something else?) looking for places it depends on one of those things.
Finally you start reading documentation to find out how to existing build infrastructure to account for the new build environment.